# Give end tag a class?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I would like to know if there is a possibility to add a class to an end tag.

I am working on a special way of a responsive table. 
Here is my idea:

```
PC view: 

 Headline1            Headline2
 Text1                Text2

Mobile view:

Headline1
Text1
Headline2
Text2
```

My idea of the code:

```
<table>
    <tr style="background-color:blue;">
        <td>headline1</td>
    </tr class="mobile">
    <tr class="mobile">
        <td>headline2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:red;">
        <td>text1</td>
    </tr class="mobile">
    <tr class="mobile">
        <td>text2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
<style>

.mobile {
    display:none;
}

    @media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 1000px)
{
    .mobile {
        display:block;
    }
}
</style>
```

Why am I not using an other solution for a responsive table or use 2 tables with display hide? Because My boss, who will work with the page has no idea about code and he would like the convenience to change it in his waziwig editor without worrying about code.

Comment: What do you expect would happen by "giving a class to the closing tag"?

Comment: No, you can't put the class in the end tag. Why is this any better than putting it in the start tag, e.g. `<tr style="background-color: red;" class="mobile">`?

Comment: "a special way of a responsive table" We do things the same for good reasons. Please explain what you are trying to achieve, there may be a normal solution.

Comment: Ah, "My boss ... would like the convenience to change it in his waziwig editor" Find a CMS or a developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely cannot hide only a start tag or only an end tag with CSS, any more than you can hide only the `<` or `>` of a tag with CSS.

CSS applies to elements, not tags; the start and end tags themselves don't even exist in the DOM.  They're just syntax.